# 1. Java is not compiled language but it is intepreted language. how? (since we compile the code to bytecode before running)

Tags: java

My understanding on this question is as :
Java compiler converts Source code to bytecode and JIT(Just-in-time) compiler converts bytecode to instructions that would be intepreted by the processor.

Can anyone please let me know better answer for this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"better answer"*? Also strictly speaking a language on it's own is rarely truly "interpreted" or "compiled", you could write a pure Java interpreter - In fact there are compilers that will transform Java code to machine code (e.g.: GCJ)

Comment: java is both compiled and interpreted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101802/1927832

Comment: It's both. Java is compiled language however `bytecode` is interpreted. Refer to this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html

Answer (score 0):

Java bytecode is generally interpreted by the Virtual Machine. JIT compiler is an enhancement to improve emulation.